# Rough approximation of option delta (or binary option) given option price wihtout implied volatility?

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

Under the Black-Scholes framework, is there any approximation of option delta (i.e., $N(d_1)$) or binary options price(i.e., $N(d_2)$) given the option price $C$?
Of course, you can calculate those once you know the implied volatility (IV). I am looking for an approximation **without** using IV. A very rough approximation is fine as long as an approximation holds the correct limit behavior (e.g., $N(d_1)$ or $N(d_2)$ goes to 0 as $C$ goes to 0).

I am looking for these approximations as an intermediate step to estimate IV because you can obtain IV once you know $N(d_1)$ or $N(d_2)$.

Comment: Or of interest, what is the use case for this?

Comment: @AKdemy, as I mentioned, I want to get a rough estimate of IV using N(d1) or N(d2).

Comment: Had to delete my initial answer - The results were quite impractical :-D

Comment: Yes, but for what purpose? Most exchanges anyhow display delta and IV on top of the market quote. If not, there are lots of fast ways to obtain IV like [this method](https://github.com/vollib/lets_be_rational).

Comment: What input do you have? A single call price or multiple call price?

If you have multiple call price $C_i$ and the corresponding underlying asset price $S_i$ (assuming the rest of the parameter are fixed), you could approximate $\Delta$ as follow:

$\Delta = \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} = N(d1) \approx \frac{C_{i+1}(S_{i+1})-C_{i}(S_{i})}{S_{i-1}-S_i}$

the smaller the quantity $S_{i+i}-S_i$ is , the better the approximation will be

Comment: @AKdemy, yes, I am aware of fast methods.
It's just curiosity and purely academic purposes.

Comment: The same methodology would work in the strike dimension, $N(d_2)\approx -e^{rT}\frac{C(X_1)-C(X_0)}{X_1-X_0}$